# Novice question - Interpreting Linear Regression Analysis

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, rapidminer

I'm looking for a very simple explanation for a project I'm working on.

I'm comparing unemployment data and median income based on level of education (Bachelors, Masters, College, Trade Certificate, None) & the major field of study.   The data come from two tables - both from the same source, one describing earnings based on education, and the other describing labour force participation.  I'm using RapidMiner to interpret the information and pull some data.  I'm not doing anything very intricate, basically filtering the data and grabbing the filtered data.

For the sake of helping with an answer, the relevant variables from Table1 is Highest_Education (String), Major_Field (String), Occupation (String), and Unemployment % (Real Number).   The relevant variables from Table2 is Highest_Education, Major_Field, and Median_Income (Integer).

I've joined the two tables together, using Highest_Education and Major_Field as primary attributes.  I have then tried to run the linear regression analysis function using unemployment% as the parameter for the regression, then again with median salary.   I've attached the results.  I would like help in interpreting them.

If anybody could give a very simplified explanation of what I'm looking at, that would be extremely helpful.  If you need any clarification, I'd be happy to help too.

The results are shown below. Maybe it means nothing, and maybe Linear Regression isn't the way to tackle this?

[image: Analysis using Unemployment%]
[image: Analysis Using Median]

Comment: Since I can't post more than two pictures, the regression results using median as a parameter are:

Name: Coefficient, Std.Error, Std. Coefficient, Tolerance, TStat, PValue
Unemployment: -12163.626, 2344.922, -0.048, 1, -5.187, 0
Intercept: 50884, 113.518, ?, ?, 448.248, 0

Comment: Sounds like you're using a wrong (?) tool for the job as you are trying to compare two groups. Did you try t-test? Even better, try the BEST method https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/BEST/

Comment: what did you mean by "tl;dr version" in your original post?  I took it out because I didn't think it was relevant, but if I'm wrong, go ahead and edit the question to put it back in.  It was also not immediately clear to me what the pictures are that I'm looking at.  Is the first of the merging process?  If so, I'd argue that your output is much more important than the picture showing the join process.  If you can edit the question to show the output you posted in your comment above, that would be more useful than the first picture.

Comment: tl;dr = Too Long, Didn't Read, but I took your advice and changed the picture to be the second output.

Comment: @xeon 

Could be the wrong method, I'm essentially only comparing two sets of numberical data, I had thought the linear regression was used for comparing those to try and find any correlation.

I'm supposed to use this program, the point being to get comfortable with it.  This aspect is more above what's expected, however I thought it would be useful to include if relevent.   I've tried using the T-test, however it involves converting the data to a 'performance vector', which I'm having zero luck doing.  

Can I assume though that your response means that the output data is meaningless?